# Word2vec tsne plot

Tags: python, plot, visualization, word2vec, dimensionality-reduction

I am trying to visualize word2vec i created from amazon reviews corpus.....i sampled about 5k positive and 5k negative rows....the score column contain whether the reviews are positive or negative....
Here's my code:
**

```
For avg w2v i did this…(list of sent contains the avg w2v for each review)
w2v_model=gensim.models.Word2Vec(list_of_sent,min_count=5,size=50, workers=4)
Y = w2v_model[w2v_model.wv.vocab]
tsne = TSNE(n_components=2, perplexity = 30)
tsne_data = tsne.fit_transform(Y)
```

**

Now i want to plot these according to the score i.e blue dots for positive and red for negative.......i don't know how to do this!!.....
Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this right, you basically want to create a scatterplot X= TSNE Component 1, Y= TSNE Component 2 and coloured by a target variable(positive or negative)

The following sample code achieves this::

```
tsneDf = pd.DataFrame(data = tsne_data ,columns = ['TSNE component 1', 
'TSNE component 2'])
 #Create a dataframe of TSNE Compoenent and the Score Column
finalDf = pd.concat([tsneDf, df[['ScoreColumn']]], axis = 1)

#Now we jsut plot a scatter plot
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (8,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1) 
ax.set_xlabel('TSNE Component 1', fontsize = 15)
ax.set_ylabel('TSNE Component 2', fontsize = 15)
ax.set_title('2 component TSNE', fontsize = 20)

#In this example 0:Negative and 1:Positive and we map respective colour
targets = [0, 1] 
colors = ['r', 'g']
for target, color in zip(targets,colors):
indicesToKeep = finalDf['ScoreColumn'] == target
ax.scatter(finalDf.loc[indicesToKeep, 'TSNE component 1']
           , finalDf.loc[indicesToKeep, 'TSNE component 2']
           , c = color
           , s = 25,alpha=0.4)
ax.legend(targets)
ax.grid()
```

Sample Result is as follows (for my data)
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the info...this did it...!!

Answer (score 0):

You have mapped your dataset into a 2-dimensions, so, data set can be transformed to 3 columns, where your x,y will be from t-SNE and positive and negative categorical column

You can plot the same using matplotlib's Scatterplot